# Force Visual Studio to open special (e.g., Excel) files instead of calling another program

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm debugging something and want to compare two Excel files that look identical in Excel.  I want to view the source somehow and see what the differences are.

The problem is that Visual Studio (2010 and 2008) both use Excel instead of opening the file itself.  Even if it's just a hex-editor view, how do I use Visual Studio to open these files instead of Excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file is in the solution explorer, you can right-click it and select Open With... Then select "Binary Editor" and click OK.

But if they are Excel 2007 files, just rename the file so it has a .zip extension instead of .xlsx and you can then unzip it and look at the xml directly.

Comment: "Open With" is also available in the File | Open dialog (see drop-down on Open button).

Comment: Is something similar available when the file is not in the solution explorer?  I can always make a new project, but it's a little inconvenient.

Comment: Woah, that unzip thing is way more helpful!  Based on what I saw in Visual Studio, I think that will work a lot better.  Thanks!

Comment: Refer to sean e's comment above. You can do it with the VS open file dialog for files not in the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the file --> Open with --> Select source (text) Editor (or whatever you want) --> click make default for this type of file.

Comment: The Source Code (Text) Editor will not open Excel files, in either 2003 or 2007 formats.

Comment: I just tried it (with encoding), and it opened it but you are correct, it is jiberish.